# Pass parameter to app config file during MSI installation - Advanced Installer

Tags: advanced-installer

I have created MSI package using advanced Installer. It contains App Config to which i have to pass the siteURL which varies depending on location. I need to pass the siteurl to app config when msi is installed . Please help me with it. I am new to Advanced Installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the online user guide for Advanced Installer, it has a lot of useful info. For example the article on [importing and editing XML config files](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-import-edit-xml-file.html).

Or how to [add a custom dialog and write in the system the values captured](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-dialog-editor.html) from the end users.

**EDIT:** *additional answer regarding command line*

You can run the installation silently from the command line but you will still see the message box saying the package is built with a trial. You will not see the standard MSI dialogs. And the trial messages will be gone once you purchase license for Advanced Installer.

Please note that your command prompt window (cmd.exe) must be launched as administrator, if your installation is installing per-machine (*i.e. you write in Program Files or HKLM registry hive*). Otherwise the installation will fail silently and you will not know why, because on silent installation the OS will not show an error message.

Here is a [command line](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html) example:

> msiexec.exe /i C:\setup\installer.msi /qn ID="235424" SiteURL="www.example.com"

Please note that it is not recommended to use [private properties](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/properties.html), i.e. properties with lower case letters in their name, we recommend public properties, for example: **SITE_URL**.

Comment: The above link really worked. Now i have to install the msi silently. Tried different things. Quiet weak in command lines. Can you please help me with a valid link. Also i have to pass the parameters with values in command line

Comment: Also i am using trial version enterprise project. Can i try out silent installation using trial version. The parameters i need to pass are : SiteURL and ID.

Comment: luckily I could figure out the above command line from articles earlier, but the issue is ,I have to include an Opticon scanner driver into the packege. since i couldn't find any INI files for that driver, the only way left was to add as pre-requisite.I have added it under feature-based pre-requisite and all works fine in Full UI mode.

Comment: But when coming to the silent installation, everything else goes silent except the driver installation part. it has got 3 dialog boxes asking for installing 3 different forms of drivers.  How can i hide that. I need to do entire installation silently (even the prerequisites)

Comment: msiexec.exe /i <folderpath> /qn SITE_URL="" ID="". This is the command line i am trying, it hides the application installation but the driver installation dailog's are still seen.

Comment: When you add a package as a prerequisite you can specify a custom command line for that package. Go to Prerequisites -> Your package -> Setup Files tab. There you find the location where to specify the command lines (read the docs of the vendor to find which are the command lines)

Comment: I am able to build the msi package including all the files required.Also i am able to install it silently.

Comment: But when trying to uninstall the package a reboot is required dialog is displayed, eventhough the system is not rebooted when clicking "OK" button for that dialog.I found that it is the Font file(PF Barcode 39) that is causing the reboot dialog box to appear as i am checking the "Register Font" option. How can i limit installing (or registering) the font based on condition.

Comment: I want to check whether the font is already installed in the Target System. if Yes do not install or overwrite the Font, if NO then install the Font. I tried SEARCH tab, created a new Search for file giving the file name of font, also tried searching in registry giving the name of the font. but i am not sure what to give in the operations tab under properties.